# How to NOT apply CSS styles from an iframe to parent site

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe

We are having a third-party development company create an application, which we plan on displaying in our WordPress site by using an iframe. However, they've coincidentally used a lot of the same CSS names that are used on our site. This is causing part of the main site to break. How can we display this application within an iframe, but without messing up the main site?

Comment: "This is causing part of the main site to break." Not if they're actually using an iframe it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

CSS within an iframe will not affect the containing page. That's just not how it works. Iframes are treated as an entirely different webpage that just happens to be embedded within another.

Comment: That's what I understand as well. When adding the iframe without content, everything renders correctly. However, when adding content within the iframe, part of the header breaks.

Comment: you'll have to post some code to duplicate your problem or make a jsfiddle

Comment: unfortunately, it is effecting and it is all the major browsers (IE, FF and Chrome). is there anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: just for the note if the URL of the css is a full url or it is referring a CDN url it is overridding the parent page, well I did not test the relative url but I am pretty sure if the css is defined in the style tag it won t effect(obviously). Just keep in mind as a work around.