# How to prevent styles leaking from v-html in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a vue component that renders multiple child components and a div with v-html directive. The div renders a dynamic HTML source. Sometimes, the styles from the HTML source leak outside the div and affect the other components.

How to prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to NOT apply CSS styles from an iframe to parent site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620539/how-to-not-apply-css-styles-from-an-iframe-to-parent-site)

Comment: Thanks, But my issue was not occurring due to the iframe, I have modified the question.

Comment: Does the rendered html renders a `<style>` tag? If so, there is no way to prevent it expect for you to manipulate the input string and tweak the `<style>` part.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to render the email body inside the v-html. So it does contain 'style' tags and I am not supposed to remove them.

Comment: Your only solution here is to update the email <style> tag so it applies only to the email html (using an `#id` on the root element for example). If you can't touch this style tag, you will have to add this `#id {}` wrapper yourself in the string you pass to `v-html`. There is no way you can tell a native `<style>` tag to only apply to a certain dom part.

Comment: you could try building a web component that is [created with vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) and render the styles inside this component. This should scope the styles only to that element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use the srcdoc property to pass raw HTML to an iframe, and the CSS doesn't bleed since an iframe is rendered "outside" the normal window:

```
<iframe :srcdoc="html"></iframe>
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc

Comment: Hi and welcome, while this can be an alternative, it would be useful to indicate how to use it in the context of the question. i.e. how to pass the srcdoc from a rendered Vue value